# Ionic, phonegap nfc Exception in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, nfc, phonegap

I am developing an Ionic app which reads nfc tags. But when I am running it in iOS I am getting the result from the nfc tag, but after that I am getting NSExcetion.

Here is the part of the code where I am trying to read NFC Tag:

```
if(this.platform.is("ios")) {
      this.nfc.beginSession().subscribe(() => {
        this.nfc.addNdefListener((data) => {
          console.log("IOS: ",data) // You will not see this, at this point the app will crash
        })
      });  
  }
```

I never get the console.log !!!!!

These are the errors that I am getting in Xcode (version 9.2):

```
2018-02-01 09:06:57.987510-0500 androidSDK[1819:852595]   readerSessionDidBecomeActive
2018-02-01 09:07:03.035369-0500 androidSDK[1819:852705] NFCNDEFReaderSession didDetectNDEFs
2018-02-01 09:07:03.035641-0500 androidSDK[1819:852705] {"ndefMessage":[{"tnf":1,"id":[],"payload":[2,101,110,72,101,108,108,111,46,33],"type":[84]},{"tnf":1,"id":[],"payload":[2,101,110,72,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100,33,32],"type":[84]}]}
2018-02-01 09:07:03.035975-0500 androidSDK[1819:852430] -[WKWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e046200
2018-02-01 09:07:03.036619-0500 androidSDK[1819:852430] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WKWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e046200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18121b164 0x180464528 0x181228628 0x18ab933c8 0x181220b10 0x181105ccc 0x104b74880 0x105cfd2cc 0x105cfd28c 0x105d01ea0 0x1811c3344 0x1811c0f20 0x1810e0c58 0x182f8af84 0x18a836804 0x104b2b1cc 0x180c0056c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2018-02-01 09:07:03.036798-0500 androidSDK[1819:852705] didInvalidateWithError Single tag read (null)
```

- Ionic version: 3.19.1
- iOS platform version: 4.5.4
- Cordova version: 8.0.0
- Phonegap-nfc plugin: phonegap-nfc 0.7.1 "NFC"

Comment: Have you tried adding in a callback function for the [failure argument of addNdefListender](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddndeflistener)? I would also recommend putting an error handler in your beginSession subscribe to make sure the session is starting (check [this](https://alligator.io/rxjs/simple-error-handling/) for error handling with RxJS).

Comment: Changed the besinSession to this.nfc.beginSession(
            (succuss) => {
              console.log("Success");
            },
            (fail) => {
              console.log("Fail");
            }
          )
I do not get the console logs!!!!

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: Making Ionic cordova prepare iOS and after that I am running the project from XCode.

Comment: Try using `ionic cordova run -c ios` in the terminal from the root of your ionic project. The `-c` will print out the console statements in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the plugin, it just works with UIWebView, but you are using WKWebView, so [this line](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/blob/master/src/ios/NfcPlugin.m#L118) fails

```
[(UIWebView*)[self webView] stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: function];
```

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc/pull/288) available to fix this problem, so click on the thumbs up button so maybe it's taken into account and merged, or use the fork instead.

Comment: You mean to pull all the project from GitHub?

Comment: You can install from the fork's branch that have the change https://github.com/andreamaioli/phonegap-nfc/tree/patch-1, or fork yourself and apply that patch, it's really small